# Is it possible to define java-style (non-static) inner class (in class scope)

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, inner-classes

For those who are not familiar with java non-static inner classes are classes where the objects has reference to the outer object from which it was created.

This may of course be realized in python by creating the class in the constructor. For example:

```
>>> class Outer:
...    def __init__(self):
...        class inner:
...            _outer = self
...        self.Inner = Inner

>>> outer = Outer()
>>> inner = outer.Inner()
>>> outer
<__main__.Outer object at 0x7f61f9d8e978>
>>> inner._outer
<__main__.Outer object at 0x7f61f9d8e978>
```

I've tried to define it in a more Java-ish manner by having it defined in the class body. For example:

```
def nonstatic(cls):
    def ctor(*args, **kwds):
        return cls(*args, **kwds)
    return ctor

class Outer:
    @nonstatic
    class Inner:
         pass
```

Which kind-of-works, but it isn't a very flexible solution. For example Outer().Inner is just a constructor and not a type. This also implies that that solution will prohib inheritance from the Inner class.

Now the question is there a solution where it could be defined at that point? Or is such an attempt doomed to fail in some way? I'm inclined to think it is doomed, but I'd like an argument why that is (or is it just going to be messy?).

I didn't mention it, but I'm looking a bit for a solution where the inner class can be instantiated with the outer object as an implicit argument, just like methods (ie `outer = inner.Outer()`)

Comment: Please don't tag non-Java questions with [tag:java], even though you're referencing Java for comparison. It flags up the question for Java folks who won't be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me, why you want to nest the classes or instantiate the inner class with an implicit argument. Please keep the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) in mind:

```
...
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
...
```

Could you please elaborate on a use case?

---

As I think nesting is not required for your example, you could simply go with something like

```
class Inner:
    def __init__(self, outer: 'Outer') -> None:
        self.outer = outer

class Outer:
    def create_inner(self) -> Inner:
        return Inner(self)

outer = Outer()
inner = outer.create_inner()

# or
inner = Inner(outer)
```

A benefit of the latter would be, that if you can use another `Inner` class (thanks to [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) or inheritance) without modifying the `Outer` class.

```
class NewInner(Inner):
    ...

outer = Outer()
inner = NewInner(outer)
```